# Opening existing project in VS 2012 RC

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, visual-studio-2012

I have a project which is build in VS 2012RC, But when i zipped the project and transfer it to my machine,extracted it and try to open solution file(.sln) in my machine which also consist of VS 2012RC, it fires a pop up that

"**This edition of Visual Studio only supports Windows Metro style apps**".

So, What do i need to do to open the project in my machine, Please let me know if am missing something, Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is pretty clear. You have the wrong version on VS2012 installed. Download the Ultimate version for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio 2012 has many editions. To me you are using VS Express edition, which only supports Metro app development. Like @leppie suggested, you might install VS Ultimate edition, which can open all sorts of projects.